# Using Deno's listen vs deno.land's http/server

Tags: httpserver, deno

I want to know what's the difference between the two :

This works as a 3rd party library like express ?

```js
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@0.168.0/http/server.ts";
serve(handler);
async function handler(req: Request): Promise<Response>
{
    const url = new URL(req.url);
    console.log("Path:", url.pathname);
}
```

Is this a natively built-in thing in Deno ?

```js
const server = Deno.listen({ port: 8000 });
for await (const conn of server)
{
    serveHttp(conn);
}
async function serveHttp(conn: Deno.Conn)
{
    const httpConn = Deno.serveHttp(conn);
    for await (const requestEvent of httpConn)
    {
        const url = new URL(requestEvent.request.url);
        console.log(url.pathname);
        console.log("Path:", url.pathname);
    }
}
```

Comment: “_I want to know the difference_”: The [`serve`](https://deno.land/std@0.172.0/http/server.ts?source#L587) function uses the [`Server`](https://deno.land/std@0.172.0/http/server.ts?source#L54) class, which uses [`Deno.serveHttp`](https://deno.land/api@v1.29.3?s=Deno.serveHttp) internally. Is that the answer you were looking for? Understanding every difference requires reviewing the entire source (linked), so any answer here can only explain a partial difference unless it copies all of the source code.

Comment: `Deno.listen` doesn't seem to require any sort of import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/std/http/server.ts` is an abstraction over `Deno.listen`. The abstraction is designed to simplifying make the most basic http server. Anything in the Deno namespace (that is to say `Deno.*`) is built into Deno itself, not requiring any imports.

> This works as a 3rd party library like express ?

For most practical use, you do not want to be using `http/server` or `Deno.*`. They don't do routing or middleware for you, so you should stick to more established routing frameworks.

I personally recommend one of the two:

- (#1) Oak - https://github.com/oakserver/oak
- (#2) Rutt - https://github.com/denosaurs/rutt

Hope that answers your question! Have a nice day!